# OneDriveException "resyncRequired" when syncing changes from two subfolders separately

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have a problem on syncing changes from OneDrive using `view.delta` (https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm) on two different subfolders. I am using OneDrive API SDK (C#).

My folder structure on OneDrive is following:

> appFolder/data/folder1
>
> appFolder/data/folder2

For some specific reasons I want to track changes on those two subfolders `folder1` and `folder2` separately, so I use two different delta tokens one for each subfolder.

The problem is that when there is a change (add/remove file) in other subfolder e.g. folder1, calling "view.delta" on that folder works properly but calling `view.delta` on the other subfolder using its own token causes OneDriveException `resyncRequired` although there have not been any changes on that folder.

Are there some problems/limitations on tracking changes of multiple folders on OneDrive (NOT OneDrive for Business)?

Sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
    static async Task Test(IOneDriveClient client)
    {
        var drive = client.Drive;

        // get app folder
        var appFolder = await drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();

        // create data folder under the app folder
        var dataFolder = await drive.Items[appFolder.Id].Children.Request().AddAsync(new Item { Name = "data", Folder = new Folder() });

        // create two subfolders folder1 and folder2 under the data folder
        var folder1 = await drive.Items[dataFolder.Id].Children.Request().AddAsync(new Item { Name = "folder1", Folder = new Folder() });
        var folder2 = await drive.Items[dataFolder.Id].Children.Request().AddAsync(new Item { Name = "folder2", Folder = new Folder() });

        // get initial token for the folder1
        string token1 = null;
        var changedItems1 = await drive.Items[folder1.Id].Delta(token1).Request().GetAsync();
        token1 = changedItems1.Token;

        // upload some test files under the folder1
        var testFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///TestData/Document.txt"));
        await UploadFileAsync(client, folder1, testFile, "file1");
        await UploadFileAsync(client, folder1, testFile, "file2");

        // get updated token for the folder1
        changedItems1 = await drive.Items[folder1.Id].Delta(token1).Request().GetAsync();
        token1 = changedItems1.Token;

        // get initial token for the folder2
        string token2 = null;
        var changedItems2 = await drive.Items[folder2.Id].Delta(token2).Request().GetAsync();
        token2 = changedItems2.Token;

        // now make some change under the folder1 (upload, delete)
        await UploadFileAsync(client, folder1, testFile, "file3");

        // get updated token for the folder1, this works ok
        changedItems1 = await drive.Items[folder1.Id].Delta(token1).Request().GetAsync();
        token1 = changedItems1.Token;

        try
        {
            // try to get changes for the folder2, this throws OneDriveException
            changedItems2 = await drive.Items[folder2.Id].Delta(token2).Request().GetAsync();
            token2 = changedItems2.Token;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Exception is thrown with the following message:
            // "Resync required. Upload any local items that the service did not return, and upload any files that differ from the server's version (keeping both copies if you're not sure which one is more up-to-date)."
        }
    }

    static async Task UploadFileAsync(IOneDriveClient client, Item destinationFolder, IStorageFile file, string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            var item = await client.Drive.Items[destinationFolder.Id].ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<Item>(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've created https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/258 to track this

Comment: Hi kine, we've been unable to reproduce your issue - are you still seeing this unexpected behavior? If so, can you provide more details if you have them (E.g. what type of resync is being suggested etc)

Comment: Hi Brad, I wrote quickly a sample code to reproduce the issue. I have not tested if the folder structure must be exactly as in the sample. As a workaround I changed my app to track changes in the root "data" folder only (using one token), so I can continue my project.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to create such a thorough repro kine!

Comment: You are welcome! My workaround (tracking the root folder `appFolder/data` only) is not perfect either. It seems that if there is any modification in `appFolder` (outside the `data` folder), the same problem occurs.

Comment: I want to list changes done on OneDrive using c# for personal account. I have used same code given above but I don't understand where the changes are list. Can you tell me how to list only changes file using same request?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the service, and not an issue with how you're using it. We're working on resolving it now - you can use [this link](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/258) to track our progress.

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: @kine just to make sure you're aware, we've resolved the issue but there is a caveat. Have a read of the GitHub comments and feel free to leave comments on the issue if you still have concerns.

Comment: So if I query for changes in `appFolder/data/folder1` I will actually get changes for ALL subfolders in `appFolder/data`? How about changes in e.g. `appFolder/data2` or `/someOtherRootFolder`, will I get changes in them too even if I am querying only `appFolder/data/folder1`?

Comment: Nah, what you'd end up seeing for your scenario, and I agree it's not ideal, is a changes call on `folder2` would return a single item (`folder2` itself) when a change was made in `folder1`, even though `folder2` itself did not change.